# How can I ignore a relationship on table using Spring CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables, Table A have several columns with item id, table B associated to Table as a many to one relations by foreign key A's item id, now I am using Spring CrudRepository trying to find all data in table A, I need all columns and all row but I dont want anything from table B because at this moment they are useless for me, is there any way that I can configure to let its ignore relationship when I use findall in CrudRepository to let it just return Pure Table A data?

I have a controller

```
@GetMapping
  public ResponseEntity<List<A>> findAll()
  {
     final List<A> aList = AService.findAll();

    final List<AResource> aResourceList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (final A a: aList)
    {
      aResourceList.add(new aResource(a));
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(aResourceList, HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

service

```
public List<A> findAll()
  {
    final List<A> aList = new ArrayList<>();

    aRepository.findAll().forEach(a -> aList.add(a));

    return aList;
  }
```

then repository

```
public interface aRepository extends CrudRepository<A, long>
{
}
```

so now if I ran this, it will grab A from table A and a list of B associated to each one of them, I would like to know is there an easy way to do this without writing my own query?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```